# issue with multiple checkbox and php

Tags: php, html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="HairCut" /> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="HairColor" />
<button name="submit" type="submit">Print</button>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

if(empty($_POST['item'])){echo "Please Select Atleast One Option";}

else {
if(in_array('HairCut', $_POST['item'])){$name = "Hair Cut";}
if(in_array('HairCut', $_POST['item'])){$price = "20";}

if(in_array('HairColor', $_POST['item'])){$name = "Hair Color";}
if(in_array('HairColor', $_POST['item'])){$price = "30";}


echo "$name:$price <br>";
}
}
?>
```

If i check both checkbox together then i get only single result like

```
Hair Color:30
```

But expectation result is both like

```
Hair Cut:20
Hair Color:30
```

Anyone able to help me regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are only echoing once!
And also you may like to optimise your if loops as below:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(empty($_POST['item'])){
        echo "Please Select Atleast One Option";
    } else {
        if(in_array('HairCut', $_POST['item'])){
            $name = "Hair Cut";
            $price = "20";
            echo "$name:$price <br>";
        }

        if(in_array('HairColor', $_POST['item'])){
            $name = "Hair Color";
            $price = "30";
            echo "$name:$price <br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I really appreciate for your help. Your code working fine. I'm sorry i think i should mention it before that i would want to make printable invoice system for my friend parlor business and i need MY SQL database also.

Comment: You mean you want to save the posted data in MySQL db?

Comment: Your code working fine if i don't use MySQL but when try to use sql then got messed up. i got only single echoing like before. sample img: http://imgur.com/a/CNMmC

Here is code:

Comment: see you are inserting only one `name` and `price` to db, and printing also one row..`SELECT` query is also limited to one.

Comment: i hope noticed that end of the script i tried to echo without SELECT query and Limit still doesn't working.
echo "$name:$price <br>";

i put limit on SELECT query bc i don't want all query. i just want last INSERT INTO query (i mean last invoice what i just added. i don't want all invoice come from DB)

Comment: I don't think you got my point. Ping me connecttobn@gmail.com - in hangouts

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along these lines perhaps where you have a predefined array of options with associated values and test if an item exists in the submitted data in order to display the item and price.

```
if( isset( $_POST['submit'], $_POST['item'] ) && !empty( $_POST['item'] ) ){

    $matrix=array(
        'haircut'   =>  20,
        'haircolor' =>  30,
        'beardtrim' =>  5,
        'shave'     =>  10
    );
    $total=0;

    foreach( $_POST['item'] as $item ){
        $key = strtolower( $item );
        if( array_key_exists( $key, $matrix ) ){
            echo "$item: {$matrix[ $key ]}<br />";
            $total += floatval( $matrix[ $key ] );
        }
    }
    echo "<br /><br />Total: {$total}";


} else {
    if( empty( $_POST['item'] ) ){
        echo 'Please select at least one option';
    }
}
```